# Evitar que se peguen letras dentro de un input

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código que evita que los usuarios escriban letras dentro del input a excepción de la letra X y números.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ejemplo").keypress(function(e) {
        var n = (e = e || window.event).keyCode || e.which,
            t = -1 != "0123456789xX".indexOf(String.fromCharCode(n));
        (t = 8 == n || n >= 35 && n <= 40 || 46 == n || t) || (e.returnValue = !1, e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault())
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ejemplo"></input>
```

**Funciona bien, sin embargo no evita que dichas letras puedan ser pegadas desde el portapapeles.** ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Actualización

Aplicando los cambios sugeridos en los comentarios por el OP y gracias al aporte de @Marcos la nueva solución pasaria a ser esta:

```js
$("#ejemplo").on("input", function(e) {
  var valorInput = e.target.value;
  const globalRegex = new RegExp('^(?![1-2])[0-9x]*$', 'gi');
  if (!globalRegex.test(valorInput)) {
    alert('Cadena incorrecta! Vuelve a empezar: ' + valorInput);
    e.target.value = ''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ejemplo">
```

Con esta nueva solución se solucionan dos problemas nuevos. A saber:

1. El OP demandó que también funcionara el filtro para la introducción del texto a mano, no solo pegándolo.
2. El OP demandó que no se permitiera la introducción de los números 1 y 2 al principio de la cadena.

La solución al punto 1 viene dada por el comentario de @Marcos, sugiriendo utilizar el evento [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), el cual controla ambos casos, tanto la introducción manual de valores como el pegarlos. Por lo tanto ya no necesitamos controlar ni el **keypress** ni el **paste**.

La solución al punto 2 viene dada por este doble cambio en la expresión regular:

```
const globalRegex = new RegExp('^(?![1-2])[0-9x]*$', 'gi');
```

donde por un lado se ha modificado el patrón, y por el otro se ha incorporado `i` (también aporte de @Marcos) a las opciones para que la búsqueda sea `case insensitive` (no sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas), reduciendo el patrón en un elemento que constaba en ambos casos, la `x`.

La nueva expresión regular, despiezada indica lo siguiente:

```
^              # inicio de la línea o cadena
   (?![1-2])   # un dígito que no empiece en el rango entre 1 y 2
   [0-9x]*     # n (*) caracteres comprendidos en el rango de 0 a 9 incluyendo la x 
$              # fin de línea
```

### Anterior respuesta

Puedes usar el evento `paste` acompañado de una comprobación con **expresión regular** para permitir o no el pegado del texto. Si cumple la condición se pega, y sino aparece un mensaje de error y no se pega nada mediante el [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) cancelando el evento.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ejemplo").keypress(function(e) {
    var n = (e = e || window.event).keyCode || e.which,
      t = -1 != "0123456789xX".indexOf(String.fromCharCode(n));
    (t = 8 == n || n >= 35 && n <= 40 || 46 == n || t) || (e.returnValue = !1, e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault())
  })

  $("#ejemplo").on("paste", function(e) {
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    const globalRegex = new RegExp('^[0-9xX]*$', 'g');
    if (!globalRegex.test(pastedData)) {
      alert('Cadena incorrecta! ' + pastedData);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ejemplo">
```

Comment: Muchas graciaaaas! Me funcionó perfectamente

Comment: De nada :-) de todos modos siempre es recomendable hacer la comprobación en el backend cuando le lleguen los datos. A javascript se le puede engañar o deshabilitar y mejor que hagas una segunda comprobación después. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, una pequeña duda, hay forma de que se pueda evitar que empiece con 1 o 2 en el input? Por ejemplo, como los número en México empiezan con 5 y en España con 3, evitar que se escriba en el input 123456789 o 23456789?

Comment: @masterguru, la respuesta es acertada, pero todavia se puede arrastrar texto al `input`. Te recomiendo revisar el evento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). Y ya que estamos, en la RegEx podes usar el flag `i`

Comment: @masterguru no funcionó, pero realmente no es importante, solo queria probar, gracias amigo! Ahora me pondré a investigar como convertirlo a PHP.

Comment: @masterguru y para hacerlo con el primer código? (no el de pegar, el de escribir)

Comment: @NotoriusSha Ale, ya he hecho los cambios, espero que ya esteis todos contentos :-)  Actualizad la página y repasad la respuesta de nuevo, gracias.

Comment: @Marcos Gracias por los aportes, han quedado incorporados a la respuestaque acabo de actualizar

Comment: Funcionando al 100! Muchísimas graciaaas @masterguru por siempre ayudarme, lo aprecio mucho.

Comment: @masterguru prometo que es la última duda :(, cómo excluyo el símbolo |? probé así: `const globalRegex = new RegExp('^(?![1-2])[0-9x|]*$', 'gi');` pero no funcionó

Comment: @masterguru era incluir, disculpa. Descubrí que al implementarlo en un textarea no funciona usando varias líneas, únicamente permite escribir/pegar una sola línea, si se pasa de una línea, no me deja. ¿Sabes cómo arreglarlo? :( Aquí te dejo mi [JsFiddle dónde lo explico con un Input y un Textarea](https://jsfiddle.net/vL42ayc6/1/)

Comment: @NotoriusSha así parece funcionar bien `const globalRegex = new RegExp('^(?![0-2])(?![7-9])[0-9x\r?\n|]*$', 'gi');`... la proxima duda abre una nueva pregunta porque nos estamos desviando mucho de la pregunta original, saludos!

Comment: Entiendo, una disculpa y muchas gracias, me funcionó bien!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134985/discussion-between-notoriussha-and-masterguru).

Comment: Olvídate del chat, no quiero entrar ahí, los comentarios alli no pueden ser eliminados y además google los indexa. No le des nunca a eso del chat a menos que eso te sea igual (a mi me molesta eso e intento no usarlo nunca). Es mejor borrar los comentarios actuales que no aportan nada a la respuesta o pregunta y reducir el ruido de los comentarios de esta respuesta.